# Allow the user to acces a specific function only once a day

Tags: flutter, dart

What if I want to make a page resets itself at 12:00 am or after specific time.

Let's say I want the user to use a specific functionality once every day. For example, if the user click on a button will sees a pic of a dag, and after 12:00 am the user can click on the button again to see another picture of another dog in a specific list of dogs' pics stored in the app. How this is can be implemented in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely there are different ways to do it. Assuming you'd like to handle the logic in the client side, you can store a local boolean value called '`seen`' in the `SharedPreferences`.

Then somewhere in your app (startup for example), you can update the value to false if the time is after midnight. Assuming you already have `SharedPreferences` setup and it's in a variable called `sharedPreferences`

```
DateTime time = DateTime.now();
String resetTime = "${time.year}-${time.month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}-${time.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} 00:00:00";
if(time.isAfter(DateTime.parse(resetTiem){
  sharedPreferences.setBool('seen', false)
}
```

Now on the other side of the code, where the user clicks to see the picture, you can check if the sharedPreferences value is true or false in order to show the picture.

```
if(sharedPreferences.getBool('seen')){
  return SomeWidgetWithThePicture;
} else {
  return AnotherWidgetWithoutPicture // tell the user they can see it after midnight
}
```